# WordPress Pagination Failing To Display

Tags: php, wordpress, function, pagination

I'm working on adding pagination to a page and I am following along on the [official codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination) but I am not getting results. Right now I want to populate pagination after 1 post per page (for testing purposes). No pagination shows, the h3 tags return empty. I have tried multiple queries other than the one below to no avail. Help is sorely needed and appreciated.

```
<?php
      $paged = (get_query_var ('paged')) ? get_query_var ('paged') : 1;
      $args = array(
        'post_type' => array('post'),
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'cat' => 5,
        'tag__not_in' => 22
      );
      $the_query = new WP_Query ( $args ); 
?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
      <!-- THE CONTENT -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
  <h3><?php next_posts_link('Next'); ?></h3>
  <h3><?php previous_posts_link('Previous');?></h3>
<?php endif;  ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: And what happens instead? What does this code do? Additionally, please don't use unneccessary tagging - `function` does not have any connection to your question

Comment: I thought my title would indicate the pagination doesn't display. I clarify this in the question now by saying the he tags come back empty. Is pagination not a function?

Comment: What do you mean by "is pagination not a function"? No, that's a basic concept which is programmed using a function. What have you tried to debug the problem? Checking variable contents? Checking whether there really should be some content?

Comment: Try changing **paged** into **page** in *$paged = (get_query_var ('paged')) ? get_query_var ('paged') : 1;*

Comment: You may want to check https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops